# Conditional logical OR operator in DotNet Core

Tags: .net-core

Iam using dotnet core api.

(OR) operator i think not logic, check below

```
string foo = "3";
if(foo != "1" || foo != "2" || foo != "3" || foo != "4")
{
return bad request(); 
}
```

**its always return bad request, whats wrong ?**

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The output you get from the above code is correct.

```
foo != "1" 
foo != "2" 
foo != "4"
```

All the above conditions are true.
Only false condition is `foo != "3"`

Over all, the expression will return `true` because you are applying OR operator. So if any of the condition is true, the overall expression is true.